# Magento 2: Custom button in admin product edit page

Tags: magento2, custom-options, admin-panel

I want to add a custom button in short description near WYSIWYG editor
[image: Check screen]
A button that will contain some text that will be copied when clicked.

Comment: you are talking about wysiwyg editor you can either show the button above it or below it , I think not at the position you want?

Comment: I want to add button somewhere close, near short description fieldset. Button will contain some code that i will use sometimes in fieldset. I want something with easy access that i can use fast.